# EXCEL: cant perform functions on result from if statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, division, zero

I have a row in an excel doc with `=if(C1=1,C21,"")`, etc. This gives me a resulting value of 255. I can't seem to do anything with this value, if I set another cell to equal the result cell, it appears as 255 also (makes sense). If I do sum(), average(), etc. of the if result cell I get 0 as an answer (doesn't make sense). I've tried copying and pasting pasting (values only) but no luck.

I'm trying to take the average of a row of these if statements, but am getting the `#DIV/0!` error. I've tried changing the if statements to `=if(C1=1,C21,0)` and using `=averageif(C50:J50,">0")` but i get the same error.

Comment: Is cell C21 actually a text value with the characters '255' instead of a number?

Comment: no, double checked, its a number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely reason is that the result isn't a number. The easiest way to check is that numbers are right justified and text is left justified.

In the image below, the top 255 is a number. The bottom is formatted as text.

[Demo justified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uU588.png)